# Rails Simple Form Bootstrap - Javascript if statement to reveal input

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I have a rails 4 app with simple form and bootstrap.

I want to ask a question in my form which asks whether users need survey responses. If the answer to that is true, then I want to ask a follow up question.  My two survey questions are:

```
<%= f.input :survey, :as => :boolean, :label => false, inline_label: 'Do you need survey responses?'  %>
<br><br>


    <%= f.input :survey_link, label: 'Where is your survey?', :label_html => { :class => 'question-data' }, placeholder: 'Include a link to your survey', :input_html => {:style=> 'width: 650px; margin-top: 20px',  class: 'response-project'} %>
```

Is JS if statement the best way to approach this task? I want to hide the second question until the user answers true to the first question.

If so, I'm having trouble understanding how to make this JS work.

I have tried:

```
 if (:survey is :true) {
    :survey_link;
}
```

I can't find any resources to help explain how to do this. Help would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously the code below depends on what the name of your `survey` and `survey_link` inputs look like in actual HTML. So if in this example it is for `@user`:

```
<% simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :survey, :as => :boolean, :label => false, inline_label: 'Do you need survey responses?'  %>
    <%= f.input :survey_link, label: 'Where is your survey?', :label_html => { :class => 'question-data' }, placeholder: 'Include a link to your survey', :input_html => {:style=> 'width: 650px; margin-top: 20px',  class: 'response-project'} %>
<% end %>
```

Then the JQuery should look like (note the `user` part - you may have to change this):

```
<script>
$(function() {
    // Hide the survey_link input
    $('input[name="user[survey_link]"]').hide();
    $('input[name="user[survey_link]"]').closest("label").hide();

    // When the survey checkbox changes
    $('input[name="user[survey]"]').change(function() {
         $('input[name="user[survey_link]"]').closest("label").toggle(this.checked);
         $('input[name="user[survey_link]"]').toggle(this.checked);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this help. I'm having trouble applying it. I'll update my post with my attempt. I really appreciate your taking the time to explain this. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much for this help. I'm having trouble applying it. It worked perfectly for the form field, but the label above it (the bit that says "where is your survey" needs to be hidden with the survey link). Please can you show me how to link the label in with the hidden field. Thank you so much, hope you have a great day.

Comment: If you want to hide the label as well just add `$('.question-data').hide();` with the other `hide()` command above and `$('.question-data').show();` with the other `show()` command.

Comment: That hides everything styled with that class (including other labels in the form that shouldn't be hidden. Is there a way to confine it to the label on this input (survey_link)? Thank you

Comment: That didn't work actually. The label isn't hidden. Is it best to make a separate CSS class for every label so that I can hide it in the way you originally showed? Thank you

Comment: Yes - that is the cleanest way if possible. Then just use `$('.specific_class').hide()` and `$('.specific_class').show()`.